# How to pass a superclass instance as an argument for a subclass instance declaration?

Tags: swift4

I want to pass a superclass instance as a parameter for a subclass declaration. For example:

```
class Dog {
      var bone: Int
      var collar: String

  init(bone: Int, collar: String){
  self.bone = bone
  self.collar = collar
}

class Doggy: Dog {
  var toy: Int

  init(bone: Int, collar: String, toy: Int){
  self.toy = toy
  super.init(bone: Int, collar: String)
  }
}

var Spike = Dog(bone:3, collar:"lol")
var Nik = Doggy(bone:3, collar: "lol", toy: 5)
```

Now, instead of the last line, I want something like

```
var Nik = Doggy(Spike, toy: 5)
```

Is there an easy way to achieve that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add another init to your `Doggy` class

```
convenience init(_ dog: Dog, toy: Int) {
    self.init(bone: dog.bone, collar: dog.collar, toy: toy)
}
```

You can call

```
var Nik = Doggy(Spike, toy: 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Method overloading will help you.
You should handle the situations.
See here for reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/
i.e, there'll be different init methods.